# Validation between 3 steps in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form divided in 3 different steps.

I want two different things:

1. Focus in input in steps 2 and 3
2. Validation for non-empty fields in steps 1 and 2

This is my code:

```js
 window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("i_am").focus();
  };

 var form = document.getElementById('register'); 
 form.noValidate = true;
 form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
         document.getElementById('youremailidMsg').innerHTML = document.getElementById('email_id').value == '' ? 'Please enter your email' : '';  
  }
   
 }, false);
 
 var questionNumber=0;
    var questions=document.querySelectorAll('.notshown');
            function next(){
              questionNumber++;

              if(questions.length>questionNumber)
              {
                    document.querySelector('.shown').classList.remove('shown');
                questions[questionNumber].classList.add('shown');
               
              }
                   
        }
```

```css
.notshown {
  display: none;            
}

.shown {
  display: block;   
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="" id="register" method="POST" action="" > 
    
    <div id="q0" class="notshown shown form-group">      
        <div class="form-group">
          step 1 
          <select id="i_am"  class="form-control">
            <option value="">Choose your gender</option>
            <option value="1-1">Men</option>
            <option value="1-2">Woman</option>
          </select>
        </div>
           <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="next()">NEXT</a>                                      
    </div>
   
    <div id="q1" class="notshown form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
          step 2   
          <input class="form-control" id="province_id" placeholder="City name" required="required">
         </div>                      
         <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="next()" type="submit">NEXT</a>                                                                                                                    
    </div>
              
    <div id="q2" class="notshown">                         
        <div class="form-group">
          step 3
          <input type="text" id="email_id"  placeholder="Your email" required="required">
          <div id="youremailidMsg"></div>        
         </div>                                                            
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >REGISTER</button>                                                                 
    </div>  
                                                                                
</form>
```

Run here
https://jsfiddle.net/h7v94mxz/9/

Comment: debugging big code is tedious.Can you please show and highlight which part is not working. There is no use of css code in this question

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: really the code works but i want the two things written in the first post. The real problem is when you run the coden for me is impossible the validation fields in steps 1 and 2, and focus in input in steps 2 or 3. when you press the next button is impossible the validation. My code is very very simple

Comment: document.getElementById("i_am").focus(); works only in first step and  var form = document.getElementById('register');...}, false); works ony in last step

Comment: Examples that include jQuery and still use statements like `document.getElementById` and `window.onload` confuse the hell out of me

Comment: Ok perfect, is a hell for you, but if you cant help me is stupid enter in a sterile discussion. You can help me or you can circumvent this great problem for me.

Comment: @lordf I was working on a solution as I left work yesterday, I will finish it and post it shortly.

Comment: @mhodges ohhhh thanks and sorry for my stupid reply :_(

Comment: @lordf Answer added. Check to see if my solution works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I rewrote this using jQuery since you included the jQuery library in your question, as well as in the fiddle you provided.

Keep in mind, I did not take the time to make this bullet-proof from a validation standpoint, but I think you should be able to take what I have and build on it.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
  var questionNumber = -1;
  var questions = $('.notshown');
  var inputSelector = "input:not(:disabled):not([readonly]), textarea:not(:disabled):not([readonly]), select:not(:disabled):not([readonly])";
  var form = $('#register');

  form.on("input change propertychange", inputSelector, function() {
    validateInput(this);
  });

  function validateInput(control) {
    var $control = $(control);
    if ($control.is("div")) {
      $control.find(inputSelector).each(function() {
        validateInput(this);
      });
    } else {
      $control.removeClass("invalid-input");
      $control.siblings(".error-message").remove();
      if ($control.val() === "") {
        $errorMessage = $("<span/>");
        $errorMessage.addClass("error-message");
        $errorMessage.text("Value cannot be empty!");
        $control.addClass("invalid-input");
        $errorMessage.insertAfter($control);
      }
    }
  }

  function next() {
    var question = $(questions[questionNumber]);
    validateInput(question);
    if (question.find(".invalid-input").length) {
      // contains invalid inputs, do not proceed
      return false;
    } else {
      questionNumber++;
      question = $(questions[questionNumber]);
      if (questions.length > questionNumber) {
        $('.shown').removeClass('shown');
        question.addClass('shown');
        // focus first input in group
        question.find(inputSelector)[0].focus();
      } else {
        console.log('submitting!');
        form.submit();
      }
    }
  }

  next();
```

```css
.notshown {
  display: none;
}
.shown {
  display: block;
}
.invalid-input {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
  background-color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="" id="register" method="POST" action="">

  <div id="q0" class="notshown form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      step 1
      <select id="i_am" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose your gender</option>
        <option value="1-1">Men</option>
        <option value="1-2">Woman</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="next()">NEXT</a>
  </div>

  <div id="q1" class="notshown form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      step 2
      <input class="form-control" id="province_id" placeholder="City name" required="required">
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="next()" type="submit">NEXT</a>
  </div>

  <div id="q2" class="notshown">
    <div class="form-group">
      step 3
      <input type="text" id="email_id" placeholder="Your email" />
      <div id="youremailidMsg"></div>
    </div>
    <a type="submit" onclick="next()" class="btn btn-danger">REGISTER</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks mhodges, works very fine :). I have a last question for your, is possible focus in input when error appears?.

Comment: Other thing @mhodges , is possible differents messages for each input? Thanks and sorry for so many questions :S

Comment: @lordf You're welcome, glad I could help! =) Did you get the focus working? It was working just fine for me, although I only tested it in Chrome.